# From String to Bigint or the other way around - What to prefer?

Tags: sql, casting, parquet

## Context

Two tables I have to join have the same column used for joining with a different underlying data-type:

```
| --------- Table A -----------| | --------- Table B -----------| 
| Col_A (String) | Col_B | ... | | Col_A (Bigint) | Col_B | ... | 
|------------------------------| |------------------------------| 
| 1233456        | ...   | ... | | 1233456        | ...   | ... | 
|------------------------------| |------------------------------|
```

Of course it would be more efficient if both tables already had `Bigint` as data-type, but it is how it is. Hence, I have to cast one of the columns during the join.

Since the answer might be very dependent on the used database etc.: I am using a `parquet`-table created and queried with `Impala` or `Hive`. Thus, for table statisitics Hive's Metastore is used.

## Question

*Which column should I cast if I want the less computational expensive join?* 
In other words: **Is it more computational expensive to cast a `String` to a `Bigint` or the other way around?**

Unfortunately, in my cluster I was unable to test timings in a reliable way. Additionally, I was unable to answer this question by looking at the docs.

```sql
-- The two join-options

-- Option 1: From String to Bigint
SELECT A.*
FROM A as A
INNER JOIN B as B on cast(A.Col_A as Bigint) = B.Col_A

-- Option 2: From String to Bigint
SELECT A.*
FROM A as A
INNER JOIN B as B on A.Col_A = cast(B.Col_A as String)
```

Comment: Why the different data types? Do ALTER TABLE to have consistent data types, and the problem is gone.

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: As stated I cannot change it and have to deal with the tables as they are.

Comment: If you cast as bigint, you may run into conversion error. It's safer to cast as char.

Answer (score -1):

There are differences between the two approaches, which might be important to consider:

- `cast(A.col_A as Bigint)` can result in an error
- `cast(B.Col_A as string)` never produces an error

On the other hand, converting to an integer removes leading zeros.  And that can be either good or bad -- depending on whether they are meaningful.

As for performance, I would suggest that you try both on your data and learn which version works better on your system.